# passing vars into mysql.connector.connect

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

In python I am trying to pass variables into the connect method like below,

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user="%s", password="%s",host="%s",database="%s") % (dbuser,dbpassword,dbhost,dbdatabase) (port is missing)
```

What would be the best way to pass values into this kind of method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a dictionary and deliver keyword arguments by [unpacking it](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
params = {
    'user': dbuser, 
    'password': dbpassword,
    'host': dbhost,
    'database': dbdatabase
}

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**params)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass them directly:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=dbuser, password=dbpassword, host=dbhost, database=dbdatabase)
```